# Yii set not beign called before beforeSave?

Tags: php, yii, model, yii-components

Small issue.. I have a table that stores some system varables as a serialized array.. In my model i have to functions for setting and getting this field into a readable form. they are:

```
public function setoptPramasString($value){
     $this->opt_pramas = '';

     $str1 = explode(',', $value);
     foreach ($str1 as $str2) {
         $myVal = explode('=>', $str2);
         $this->opt_pramas[trim($myVal[0])] = (string)trim($myVal[1]);   
         echo "<BR>".$myVal[0]." => ".$myVal[1];
     }
 }

/**
 * 
 */
 public function getoptPramasString(){
     $str = '';
     $x = 0;
     foreach ($this->opt_pramas as $key => $value) {
         if($x == 0){
            $str .= $key."=>".$value;
             $x++;
         }else{
             $str .= ", ".$key."=>".$value;
         }

     }
```

**my before save and after find functions are:**

```
/**
 * 
 */
 public function beforeSave(){

     $this->opt_pramas = serialize($this->opt_pramas);
     return parent::beforeSave();
 }

 /**
  * 
  */
  public function afterFind(){
      $this->opt_pramas = unserialize($this->opt_pramas);
      return parent::afterFind();
  }
```

**My update action in the controller is:**

```
public function actionUpdate($id)
{
    $model=$this->loadModel($id);

    // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
    // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

    if(isset($_POST['SystemMenuSearch']))
    {
        $model->attributes=$_POST['SystemMenuSearch'];
        if($model->save()){
            $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->search_id));    
        }
    }

    $this->render('update',array(
        'model'=>$model,
    ));
}
```

What seems to be happening is that the `beforeSave` function is being called before the `setoptPramaString` function. Is this a bug in Yii or am I missing something? 
My logic would be that when the values are set to the models attributes it would fire the `setoptPramaString` function and then when save is called on the model it would fire the `beforeSave` function in the model. I check my form and the name is correct, `SystemMenuSearch[optPramaString]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you mass-assign your parameters through setAttributes property

```
$model->attributes = $_POST[SystemMenuSearch];
```

they will be ignored because they are not in the safe attributes list

Comment: Thank you... So if i add `optPramasString` to the safe attributes list the mass-assign function should work.. Correct?

Answer (score 1):

The issue seems to be that when you assign a batch of varables using `$model->attributes = $_POST[SystemMenuSearch]` the `setoptPramasString` function is not fired. I am unsure if this is a bug or by design.

instead you need to call:

```
$model->attributes = $_POST[SystemMenuSearch];
$model->optPramasString = $_POST[SystemMenuSearch][optPramasString];
```

This seems to be against logic but may be because restrictions in the framework or PHP.

Hopes this helps others..